# How to reuse swagger 2.0 string pattern definition?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm defining the following in swagger 2.0 "definition" section. I first defined the format of timestamp that I would use in many object's properties for different purposes, such as created timestamp and last updated timestamp.

```
definitions:
  TimeStamp:
    title: Timestamp format
    description: ISO 8681, "2016-08-18T17:33:00Z"
    type: string
    pattern: \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z
  Application:
    title: An application
    type: object
    properties:
      cDtm:
        title: Creation timestamp
        description: Some description
        type: string
        pattern:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z
```

However, when defining the "cDtm" property of the "Application" object, I cannot find a way to reuse the timestamp definition. If I use "$ref" along with "title" and "description", I get a warning "sibling values are not allowed alongside '$ref'". If I don't use "$ref", I need to repeat the type and pattern definition as above.

So, my question is, is there a way to use $ref to reuse a string pattern definition but still able to give the defined property a new title and description?

Thanks!

Bing

Comment: Did you mean ISO *8601*?

Comment: It's ISO 8601 but the question is more general, about how to reuse a string pattern definition with a new title & description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification includes built-in `format: date-time` for this format, so you don't actually need a `pattern` here. Instead, use:

```yaml
type: string
format: date-time
```

If, for some reason, you want to stick with the `pattern`, you can use the following workaround. Basically, you can "add" properties to a `$ref` if you wrap the `$ref` into `allOf`. This works in Swagger Editor and Swagger UI, but other tooling support may vary.

```yaml
  Application:
    title: An application
    type: object
    properties:
      cDtm:
        title: Creation timestamp
        description: Some description

        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/TimeStamp'
```

Also keep in mind that `pattern` works as a partial match by default. To force an exact match, enclose the pattern expression into `^..$`:

```
pattern: ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z$
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "allOf" solution and the ^..$ expression. Yes this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: A dummy title
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /post:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              required:
                - msisdn
                - network
              properties:
                msisdn:
                  title: "msidn"
                  description: "msidn"
                  allOf:
                    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/msisdn-regex"
                msisdn1:
                  title: "msidn1"
                  description: "msidn1"
                  allOf:
                    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/msisdn-regex"  
                msisdn2:
                  title: "msidn2"
                  description: "msidn2"
                  allOf:
                    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/msisdn-regex"
                IMEI:
                  type: integer
                Network:
                  type: string
              example:   # Sample object
                msisdn: "10"
                IMEI: 20
                Network:
                - Vodafone
                - Jio
                - Airtel
        required: true        
            
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
servers:
  - url: http://httpbin.org
components:
  schemas:
    msisdn-regex:
      type: string
      pattern: ^[0-9]{10}$
      example: "1234567897"
```